# convert object dytpes to numeric in numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

this is a subset of my numpy array:

```
a
Out[38]: 
array([['12,001', '9,815', '18,552'],
       ['8,175', '6,161', '13,171'],
       ['1,675', '1,736', '1,679'],
       ['60', '63', '66'],
       ['1,262', '1,231', '(1,731)']], dtype=object)
```

i wish to convert the above values to numeric dtype (np.float). I have tried a few things such as:

1) `thousands = ',' parameter in pd._read_csv`

2) `import locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')`

a solution that works is:

```
a = a.astype(np.character)
a = np.char.replace(a, ',', '')
```

but how can i provide multiple replace parameters in one go! like replace thousands separator `(',')` and replace negative sign, say `(2.8)` which reads like char to `-2.8`float.

although this methods might seem to work, i trust, it is still looping over every element of the array, is there a more powerful and faster method in numpy or pandas to achieve what i want?

Comment: Where did this array come from? You seem to be reading it from a file. Show us the code that creates the array, and if it reads from a file, show us a short example file that produces the behavior you're asking about.

Comment: The `(1,731)` value seems like the hardest part to deal with here. Why are those parentheses there?

Comment: it is because i get the data from an external source (and they choose to format the numbers to make it difficult for us to use it:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.char` has functions that apply string methods to string elements of an array.  They iterate through the elements, so aren't particularly fast.

```
In [69]: arr = np.array([['12,001', '9,815', '18,552'],
    ...:        ['8,175', '6,161', '13,171'],
    ...:        ['1,675', '1,736', '1,679'],
    ...:        ['60', '63', '66'],
    ...:        ['1,262', '1,231', '(1,731)']], dtype=object)

In [71]: np.char.replace(arr,',','')
...
TypeError: string operation on non-string array
```

Can't apply these to object dtype; got to convert to string dtype

```
In [72]: arr = arr.astype(str)
In [73]: arr
Out[73]: 
array([['12,001', '9,815', '18,552'],
       ['8,175', '6,161', '13,171'],
       ['1,675', '1,736', '1,679'],
       ['60', '63', '66'],
       ['1,262', '1,231', '(1,731)']], 
      dtype='<U7')

In [75]: arr=np.char.replace(arr,',','')
In [76]: arr
Out[76]: 
array([['12001', '9815', '18552'],
       ['8175', '6161', '13171'],
       ['1675', '1736', '1679'],
       ['60', '63', '66'],
       ['1262', '1231', '(1731)']], 
      dtype='<U6')
In [78]: arr=np.char.replace(arr,'(','')
In [79]: arr=np.char.replace(arr,')','')
In [80]: arr.astype(int)
Out[80]: 
array([[12001,  9815, 18552],
       [ 8175,  6161, 13171],
       [ 1675,  1736,  1679],
       [   60,    63,    66],
       [ 1262,  1231,  1731]])
```

Another approach would be to find or define a function that works with each string converting it to a number, and apply that to all elements with something like `frompyfunc` (or `np.vectorize`).  For example, you could use a `re` expression to replace the `,()` all at once.

```
 import re
 def mysub(astr):
     return int(re.sub(r'[,\(\)]','',astr))
 f = np.frompyfunc(mysub,1,1)
 f(arr)
```

producing:

```
array([[12001, 9815, 18552],
       [8175, 6161, 13171],
       [1675, 1736, 1679],
       [60, 63, 66],
       [1262, 1231, 1731]], dtype=object)
```

and with `.astype(int)`

```
array([[12001,  9815, 18552],
       [ 8175,  6161, 13171],
       [ 1675,  1736,  1679],
       [   60,    63,    66],
       [ 1262,  1231,  1731]])
```

Comment: the second approach of writing a function is probably way to go. However, the elements with parenthesis are negatives so that care needs to be taken in defining the replace pattern

Comment: here is my solution, it is similar in essence to what you propose, so i will accept yours:

1) a = np.char.array(t.values.astype(np.character)) # where t is the pandas dataframe / 

2) a = a.replace(',','').replace("(",'-').replace(")",'') /

3) t = pd.DataFrame(a, dtype = np.float64, columns = t.columns, index = t.index)

Answer (score 0):

One way you can deal with this is using the Pandas package, which has convenient string manipulation tools. For example:

```
data = array([['12,001', '9,815', '18,552'],
              ['8,175', '6,161', '13,171'],
              ['1,675', '1,736', '1,679'],
              ['60', '63', '66'],
              ['1,262', '1,231', '(1,731)']], dtype=object)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for col in df:
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(',', '')
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace('(', '-')
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(')', '')

new_data = df.astype(float).values
print(new_data.dtype)
# float64
```

Comment: Thank you. but replacing the parenthesis is not enough, it has to read the negative numbers correctly, I guess, the solution you propose will  inadvertently convert negative to positive

Comment: pd,read_csv(converters = {lambda x: x.replace(',','') will do this while reading the file from the source, but again, cleaning negative numbers and speed efficiency will remain.

Comment: Oh, I see. You can replace ')' with the empty string and replace '(' with '-', and you'll get the result you want. I've updated the answer.